# Bootstrap responsive row height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot seem to find this anywhere yet it seems to simple.

I have a full width website using .container-fluid. The site is divided up into full width rows. I want the rows to be responsive in height. (if the row fills about half the viewport on a desktop, it shrinks to fill about half the viewport on a tablet)

I would highly appreciate explanations with sample code vs "here use this..."

Thanks!

Comment: No code or information about what you tried is a sure fire way to get your question closed (and not answered).  I would suggest spending a bit more time trying to generate a question with more info about what you have tried, etc

Answer (score 3):

You should think about using [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw): `vh`

So, if you want a row to be half the height of the viewport, on any device it's on, use `50vh`

### [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ca2hpfa1/1)

Comment: Good answer. See more about vh and other relative measurements here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score -1):

It is for may solution. But one way is the viewport unit. This is a best way for the make responsive div height.

```css
.row {
  background: #c62222;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">HALF RESPONSIVE DIV</div>
<div class="row">HALF RESPONSIVE DIV</div>
```

*Open this url:*
https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

[image]

Comment: lol, nice, copy my code for your own answer.

Comment: This is not my motive. If u feel bad then i could delete my post.